# Ruby on Rails - rake db:migrate is not working

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database

I am using `def change` for models. Here is migration output of my models:

```
$ rake db:migrate
== 20150802221545 CreateUsers: migrating ======================================
-- create_table(:users)
   -> 0.3319s
== 20150802221545 CreateUsers: migrated (0.3322s) =============================

== 20150802221550 CreatePages: migrating ======================================
-- create_table(:pages)
   -> 0.2457s
-- add_index(:pages, :subject_id)
   -> 0.2487s
-- add_index(:pages, :permalink)
   -> 0.2464s
== 20150802221550 CreatePages: migrated (0.7416s) =============================

== 20150802221558 CreateSubjects: migrating ===================================
-- create_table(:subjects)
   -> 0.2453s
== 20150802221558 CreateSubjects: migrated (0.2456s) ==========================

== 20150802221603 CreateSections: migrating ===================================
-- create_table(:sections)
   -> 0.2776s
-- add_index(:sections, :page_id)
   -> 0.2484s
== 20150802221603 CreateSections: migrated (0.5265s) ==========================
```

Now, I created a migration named **AlterUsers** and wrote following code.

```
 - class AlterUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
        reversible do |dir|
        dir.up {
            rename_table :users, :admin_users
            add_column :admin_users, :username, :string, :limit => 25
            #add_column("admin_users", "username", :string, :limit => 25)
            change_column :admin_users, :email, :string, :limit => 100
            #change_column("admin_users", "email", :string, :limit => 100)
            rename_column :admin_users, :password, :hashed_password
            #rename_column("admin_users", "password", "hashed_password")
            add_column :admin_users, :salt, :string, :limit => 40
            #add_column("admin_users", "salt", :string, :limit => 40)
            puts "*** about to add index ***"
            add_index :admin_users, :username
            #add_index("admin_users", "username")
        }

        dir.down{

            remove_index :admin_users, :username
            remove_column :admin_users, :salt
            rename_column :admin_users, :hashed_password, :password
            change_column :admin_users, :email, :string, :default=> "", :null => false
            remove_column :admin_users, :username, :string, :limit => 25
            raname_table :admin_users, :users
        }
    end
  end
end
```

I used `def change` as I am using rails4. But rake db:migrate doesn't affect database. Then I wrote same code as instructor's code:

```
    class AlterUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
        rename_table :users, :admin_users
        add_column :admin_users, :username, :string, :limit => 25
        change_column :admin_users, :email, :string, :limit => 100
        rename_column :admin_users, :password, :hashed_password
        add_column :admin_users, :salt, :string, :limit => 40
        puts "*** about to add index ***"
        add_index :admin_users, :username
    end

  def self.down
        remove_index :admin_users, :username
        remove_column :admin_users, :salt
        rename_column :admin_users, :hashed_password, :password
        change_column :admin_users, :email, :string, :default=> "", :null => false
        remove_column :admin_users, :username, :string, :limit => 25
        raname_table :admin_users, :users
  end
end
```

It worked. After all these migrations, I am trying to undo by using this command `rake db:migrate VERSION=0`. But it's not working. Here is db migration status:

```
$ rake db:migrate:status

database: mysqlapp_development

 Status   Migration ID    Migration Name
--------------------------------------------------
   up     20150802221545  Create users
   up     20150802221550  Create pages
   up     20150802221558  Create subjects
   up     20150802221603  Create sections
   up     20150802221735  Alter users
```

And here is `rake db:migrate --trace` output

```
$ rake db:migrate --trace
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
** Invoke db:_dump (first_time)
** Execute db:_dump
** Invoke db:schema:dump (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Invoke db:load_config 
** Execute db:schema:dump
```

Now I have following major **queries** in addition to above problem.
1) In which cases `rake db:migrate` doesn't affect? (I'm confused because of it's working behaviour)
2) How to redo the undo/roll back migrations?

Comment: Run `rake db:migrate:status` which will show you whether the migrations you rollback were done or not. It should show down on all migrations if not then your migrations have not been reverted and that may be the reason your `rake db:migrate` is not running.

Comment: @Deep It rolledback. Infact I am learning thorugh lectures. I am trying to do same as instructor is doing. Once again, I am trying to do same what I did above. Now it's not going to roll back. Same status before and after this instruction: rake db:migrate:status Can you please tell me why is this happening? Where am I doing wrong? Thanks for your time in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should simply split this into several migrations. Just use `change` and let rails deal with creating the reverse migration.

**Given:**

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :email
      t.string :password
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

**Migrations:**

```
class ChangeUsersTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    rename_table :users, :admin_users
  end
end
```

---

```
class AddHashedPasswordToAdminUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
     # you should not just migrate the plaintext passwords!
    remove_column :admin_users, :password, :string
    add_column :admin_users, :password_hash, :string
    add_column :admin_users, :salt, :string, limit: 40
  end
end
```

---

```
class AddUserNameToAdminUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :admin_users, :username, :string
  end
end
```

**Result:**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150802210303) do   
  create_table "admin_users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email"
    t.datetime "created_at",               null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",               null: false
    t.string   "password_hash"
    t.string   "salt",          limit: 40
    t.string   "username"
  end
end
```

### Don't roll your own password encryption!

I would also recommend that you use [`has_secure_password`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html) rather than rolling your own password encryption. Its way to easy to mess it up.

In that case the migration would be:

```
class AddPasswordDigestToAdminUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
     # you should not just migrate the plaintext passwords!
    remove_column :admin_users, :password, :string
    add_column :admin_users, :password_digest, :string 
    # has_secure_password concatenates the salt into the digest.
    # no salt column needed.
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm guessing that this is just a learning application and you do not have any actual users. If you do you need your users to reset their passwords. You should not just rename the passwords column as you do not want any cleartext passwords to be in your database as it is a security hazard. Also any authentication method with tries to validate a user from an encrypted password  but gets a cleartext pw would fail.

Comment: Thanks Max. It's really a good practice to do in this way. You're right that I am in learning phase. Therefore, I am doing same as instructor does in his lectures. I am getting this error. This is why, I am here. I am here to know about the reason "why rake db:migrate is not working".

Comment: Wow, did your instructor really tell you should be writing out the migration in one big lump and specifying the up / down parts? I guess the proverb *those who cannot do  teach* is really true. If you have to troubleshoot that monstrosity you would run `rake db:migrate:status`. If you migration is failing vocally with a error message then read the stack trace.

Comment: No, he didn't say any such thing. Infact he is giving idea of Migration Methods. Therefore, he wrote all those migrations in a single part.  Once again, I am trying to do same what I did above. Now it's not going to roll back. Same status before and after this instruction: rake db:migrate:status Can you please tell me why is this happening? Where am I doing wrong? Thanks for your time in advance.

P.s. I am getting lectures from "lynda"

Comment: I would need to know the exact status of the database before the migration to be able to tell you what the exact issue in your migration. If you want to know what you are doing wrong is that you are lumping it all into one migration and doing Rails 2 style up/down blocks. You can do it that way but it's just plain stupid when better ways exist.

Comment: Here is db status before migration: 

`$ rake db:migrate:status 
database: mysqlapp_development 

Status Migration ID Migration Name 
-------------------------------------------------- 
up 20150802221545 Create users 
up 20150802221550 Create pages 
up 20150802221558 Create subjects 
up 20150802221603 Create sections 
down 20150802221735 Alter users 
>`

Comment: Here is db status after migration:

`$ rake db:migrate:status

database: mysqlapp_development

 Status   Migration ID    Migration Name
--------------------------------------------------
   up     20150802221545  Create users
   up     20150802221550  Create pages
   up     20150802221558  Create subjects
   up     20150802221603  Create sections
   up     20150802221735  Alter users`

Now I am trying to rollback by using this command: `rake db:migrate VERSION=0` It's not working. Same status is shown.

Comment: You still don't get what I'm saying. There is no way that lets me figure out what is wrong with your migration. I would need to know exactly what the database looked like before the migration and then troubleshoot it line by line. I'm not going to do that - I have better things to do. If you want that sort of help you should make sure your question includes a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Nobody can just look into their crystal ball and figure out what went wrong without knowing the previous state and what your expected result is.